# Zig slice to C pointer of void pointers

Tags: zig

I have a Zig slice of bytes, i.e. `[]u8`, and a C dependency expects a `void**` as an argument. How do I cast or convert the former into the latter?

Answer (score 1):

`void**` is a pointer to an anyopaque, equivalent to `[*][*]anyopaque` in zig. In c, this might be referring to an array of any-pointers? or just a weirdly typed byte array.

```
// assuming it just wants a pointer to a byte array
const slice: []const u8 = "123456";
c_function(@ptrCast(**anyopaque, slice.ptr));
```

```
// an array of anyopaque pointers
const slice = "123456";
const items: [*]*anyopaque = &[_]*anyopaque{@ptrCast(*anyopaque, slice.ptr)};
```

```
// *anyopaque to []u8
@ptrCast([*]u8, @alignCast(@alignOf(u8), c_pointer))[0..c_length]
```

Answer (score 0):

extern your function argument with a pointer

**c.c**

```c
void gg(void **a) {
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

**main.zig**

```rs
extern fn gg(a: [*:0]const u8) void;

pub fn main() void {
    gg("hello");
}
```

```sh
$ zig run c.c main.zig -lc
hello
```

Comment: Is that the only way? I'm doing a `usingnamespace @cImport` and `@cInclude`, so I'm not sure I can override the C function.

Comment: i think. what's your problem with that?